# How to convert generated id, list-of-index values tuple to a one hot encoded sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to figure the best way to turn my data into a numpy/scipy sparse matrix. I don't need to do any heavy computation in this format. I just need to be able to convert data from a dense, too-large-for-memory csv to something I can pass it into an sklearn estimator. My theory is that the sparse-ified data should fit in memory.

Because all of the features are categorical, I'm using a generator to iterate over the file and the hashing trick to one hot encode everything:

```
def get_data(train=True):
    if traindata:
        path = '../originalData/train_rev1_short_short.csv'
    else:
        path = '../originalData/test_rev1_short.csv'

    it = enumerate(open(path))
    it.next()  # burn the header row
    x = [0] * 27  # initialize row container
    for ix, line in it:
        for ixx, f in enumerate(line.strip().split(',')):
            # Record sample id
            if ixx == 0:
                sample_id = f

            # If this is the training data, record output class
            elif ixx == 1 and train:
                c = f

            # Use the hashing trick to one hot encode categorical features
            else:
                x[ixx] = abs(hash(str(ixx) + '_' + f)) % (2 ** 20)

        yield (sample_id, x, c) if train else (sample_id, x)
```

The result are rows like this:

```
10000222510487979663 [1, 3, 66642, 433470, 960966, ..., 802612, 319257, 80942]
10000335031004381249 [1, 2, 87543, 394759, 183945, ..., 773845, 219833, 64573]
```

Where the first value is the sample ID and the list is the index values of the columns that have a '1' value.

What it is the most efficient way to turn this into a numpy/scipy sparse matrix? My only requirements are fast row-wise write/read and sklearn compatibility. Based on the scipy documentation, it seems like the [CSR matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) is what I need, but I'm having some trouble figuring out to convert the data I have while using the generator construct.

Any advice? Open also to alternate approaches, I'm relatively new to problems like this.

Comment: Why not use the `FeatureHasher` from scikit-learn to do the hashing? That produces CSR matrices directly.

Comment: @larsmans as I understand it, that would require loading my entire dataset into memory first, which isn't possible in this case. If that isn't correct then yea that would probably be a better option.

Comment: For some reason I thought that your data were sparse but densely encoded on disk - I guess because of the "too-large-for-memory" remark. But looking at your code closely, you seem to have 27-dimensional vectors of categorical features. This does lend itself to `FeatureHasher` as indicated by @larsmans. What I still don't understand now is the "too-large-for-memory" part: A sparse matrix which one-hot encodes your features will take up the same order of memory, usually a bit more, unless you allow for a lot of collisions.

Comment: Correct, 27 dimensional vectors of categorical features. By "too-large-for-memory" I mean that the dataset is larger than the 8GB of memory I have available to me, but not much larger. I made an assumption that a sparse matrix which is one-hot encoded would be smaller than the dense version I have on disk, especially since many of the feature values themselves are hashed, i.e. 'd41d8cd9'. If that assumption turns out to be incorrect, then I have a very different problem I suppose...

Comment: `FeatureHasher` is designed to work on iterables. If it required having all the data in memory, it would be rather useless :)

Comment: Thanks @larsmans, confirmed that FeatureHasher does indeed work with generators. However, even the sparse matrix that results is not as small as I was hoping (as eickenberg predicted), so now I don't know that I've made any progress...

Comment: @larsmans feel free to write up an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @acpigeon I would if I understood what your data looks like. You can post an answer to your own question, too (I'm not in it for the rep points, I have those already :). Re: progress, do you need the whole matrix in memory? Do your results suffer greatly if you narrow the matrix to, say, `2**18` features?

Comment: @larsmans good question. I'm now in a position to start figuring that out. It's possible I could find a way to fit the thing in memory (or just use AWS), but I'm enjoying working within these constraints. I was able to figure out how to work with a dense matrix line-by-line, if you're interested you can see what I'm doing here: https://github.com/acpigeon/kaggle_ctr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data format is almost the internal structure of a `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` (list of lists). You should first generate one of those, and then call `.tocsr()` on it to obtain the desired csr matrix.

A small example on how to populate these:

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

positions = [[1, 2, 10], [], [5, 6, 2]]
data = [[1, 1, 1], [], [1, 1, 1]]

l = lil_matrix((3, 11))
l.rows = positions
l.data = data

c = l.tocsr()
```

where `data` is just a list of lists of ones mirroring the structure of `positions` and `positions` would correspond to your feature indices. As you can see, the attributes `l.rows` and `l.data` are real lists here, so you can append data as it comes. In that case you need to be careful with the `shape`, though. When `scipy` generates these `lil_matrix` from other data, then it will put arrays of `dtype object`, but those are almost lists, too.

Comment: You can also write `data = [[1] * len(row) for row in positions]`

Comment: I ended up not bothering with the sparse matrix as it turned out to not save me any memory. However, as far as I can tell, this would be the approach I would have used had I decided to continue down that route, so I'm accepting this as an answer.